# Select by Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, select

I know it is possible in arcpy. Finding out if can happen in pandas.

I have the following

```
data= {'Species':[ 'P.PIN','P.PIN','V.FOG', 'V.KOP', 'E.MON', 'E.CLA', 'E.KLI', 'D.FGH','W.ERT','S.MIX','P.PIN'], 
  'FY':[ '2002','2016','2018','2010','2009','2019','2017','2016','2018','2018','2016']}
```

I need to select all the P.PIN, P.RAD and any other species starting with E that have a FY equal to or older than 2016 and put into a new dataframe.

How can I get this done. All I am able to select P.PIN and P.RAD but have adding in all the other starting with E;

```
df3 =df[(df['FY']>=2016)&(df1['LastSpecies'].isin(['P.PIN','P.RAD']))]
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `c=df['Species'].isin(['P.PIN','P.RAD'])|df['Species'].str.startswith('E') ` and then `df[c]` ?

Comment: Worked. Thanks     ' df3 =df1[(df1['FY']>=2016)&(df1['LastSpecies'].isin(['P.PIN','P.RAD']))|df['Species'].str.startswith('E')]
df3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step way. But you can also combine the logic inside the `np.where()` just want to show that all conditions were done.

Start by typecasting your `df['FY']` values as int so we can use the greater than (>) operator.

```
>>> df['FY'] = df['FY'].astype(int)

>>> df['flag'] = np.where(df['Species'].isin(['P.PIN', 'P.RAD']), ['Take'], ['Remove'])
>>> df
   Species    FY    flag
0    P.PIN  2002    Take
1    P.PIN  2016    Take
2    V.FOG  2018  Remove
3    V.KOP  2010  Remove
4    E.MON  2009  Remove
5    E.CLA  2019  Remove
6    E.KLI  2017  Remove
7    D.FGH  2016  Remove
8    W.ERT  2018  Remove
9    S.MIX  2018  Remove
10   P.PIN  2016    Take

>>> df['flag'] = np.where((df['FY'] > 2016) & (df['Species'].str.startswith('E')), ['Take'], df['flag'])
>>> df
   Species    FY    flag
0    P.PIN  2002    Take
1    P.PIN  2016    Take
2    V.FOG  2018  Remove
3    V.KOP  2010  Remove
4    E.MON  2009  Remove
5    E.CLA  2019    Take
6    E.KLI  2017    Take
7    D.FGH  2016  Remove
8    W.ERT  2018  Remove
9    S.MIX  2018  Remove
10   P.PIN  2016    Take

>>> new_df = df[df['flag'].isin(['Take'])][['Species', 'FY']]
>>> new_df
   Species    FY
0    P.PIN  2002
1    P.PIN  2016
5    E.CLA  2019
6    E.KLI  2017
10   P.PIN  2016
```

Hope this helps :D